# Two columns in homepage each with one category

Tags: categories, customization, html, columns

I modifying a wordpress template to be left with two columns on the main page with the following structure:

[image]

The first 4 are of a category and the last 4 of another

The index code is:

http://pastebin.com/dMC0saBN

The page is (Columns are made, but all they do is repeat the post. They haven't order or filter)

Comment: The code should be embedded in the Question too, but that's too much, IMO. Note that pure CSS or HTML questions are off-topic ([faq]). What's the exact problem, making two queries to get those posts?

Comment: I created the 2 columns on my page, but the problem is I can't separate the two columns for each different show only post of different categories. [The code of the index.php file is in the question]

Comment: Sorry, the Question should contain the code, not an external site. And I suggest you shorten it to the essentials, it's too much code.

Comment: Does the `$high_query()` loop output the expected posts?

Comment: @ChipBennett if you check the link in the first comment you'll see that the same set of posts shows up twice, once per column.

Comment: Please put all relevant information **in your question**. Links to arbitrary sites have content that can and will change over time. If the observed issue is that one loop outputs posts correctly, but the second one does not, that information is rather important to answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Before line # 43, call wp_reset_query like the following and it should fix your repeated post problem

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this before your second query:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

It will restore your **$post** global, which should help your second occurence of `have_posts` and `the_post` to work properly.

That's how I generally do multiple queries on one page. I'm manually saving and restoring the **$post** global, but either way should work fine.

```
<?php if(have_posts()) while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

<article class="single-article" id="article-<?= $post->ID ?>">
<!-- output the page content here -->
</article>
<? endif ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- start first custom query output -->
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array(
    'meta_key'        => 'featured',
    'meta_value'      => '1',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'post_type'       => 'post' );

$featured_posts = get_posts( $args );

if( !empty($featured_posts) ): ?>

<section id="featured-posts">
    <? foreach( $featured_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <!-- and so on -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</section>

<?php endif; $post = $tmp_post; /* restore global post variable */ ?>

<!-- start second custom query output -->
<?php
$tmp_post = $post;
$story_args = array(
    'meta_key'         => 'featured',
    'meta_value'       => '1',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'post_type'        => 'story' );

$story_posts = get_posts( $story_args );

if( !empty($story_posts) ): ?>

<section id="stories">
    <? foreach( $story_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <!-- and so on -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</section>

<?php endif; $post = $tmp_post; /* restore global post variable */ ?>
```